# Azure D4 Disk Size below advertised

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Azure VM D4 is advertised as having 400GB of SSD backed storage. Provisioning the VM I end up with 127GB for the OS and 400GB for temp storage.
Is this normal? I need the full 400GB on the OS drive and dont see an obvious way to reconfigure storage.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. However, because the local SSD is not guaranteed to be persistent, you will not want this to be responsible for your OS drive.

In the D-series announcements, http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/22/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/

"Local Storage SSD Drive

On these new sizes, the temporary drive (D:\ on Windows, /mnt or /mnt/resource on Linux) are local SSDs. This high-speed local disk is best used for workloads that replicate across multiple instances, like MongoDB, or can leverage this high I/O disk for a local and temporary cache, like SQL Server 2014’s Buffer Pool Extensions. ***Note, these drives are not guaranteed to be persistent. Thus, while physical hardware failure is rare, when it occurs, the data on this disk may be lost, unlike your OS disk and any attached durable disks that are persisted in Azure Storage.***" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Found this post that explains how this is normal for the OS drive.
https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/25/azure-vm-os-drive-limit-octupled/

So for marketplace images the guidance is to provision new data drives.